# How to separate this ODE?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> Find the general solution to the first-order differential equation $$(4-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

I'm painfully stuck on this ODE with no clear idea on how to approach solving it. The method I tried was wrong due to algebraic mishaps. Can someone please give me an idea on how to break this up so I can solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\cdot \frac{1}{x^2-4}$$

so it is of the type $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)\cdot g(y)$$ where $g(y)=y$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-4}$.

---

Now, apply the standard method of solving such equations, i.e. one that you probably learned in class and goes something like [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx). What do you get?

Comment: See, I did this approach, got $\int(1/(x^2-4) = \int(1/y)$ and did partial fractions etc, however I got y = (x-2)/(x+2) + C, yet this was not the correct answer. Based on what you've said my seperation was valid, and I've checked the integrals; so I must of made a mistake at the end to find the explicit solution.

For reference, the answer I need to end up with is $(2+x)y^4 = C(2-x)$

Comment: @PixelRain What was the equation you got immediatelly after integrating?

Comment: @PixelRain Better yet, tell me how you got the partial fractions. What is $\frac{1}{x^2-4}$ equal to?

Comment: $-log(x+2)/4+log(x-2)/4 + C = log(y)$

Comment: @PixelRain That's correct, if $\frac14$ is *outside* the logarithm. Now, multiply the equation by $4$ and use the fact that $a\cdot \log(y)=\log(y^a)$ for any real number $a$.

Comment: so I should get $log((x-2)/(x+2)) + C = log(y^4)$ ?

Comment: @PixelRain Yes. And now define $C'$ as $C'=e^C$ so you get $C=\log C'$. That way, the equation becomes $\log\left(C'\cdot \frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)=\log(y^4)$.

Answer (score 2):

First, get the term without the derivative to the other side of the equation.
$$(4-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} = -y\\
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x^2-4}$$
Now you can separate the variables and use integration to get the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformulate it by

$$ \frac{1}{y} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}  = \frac{1}{x^2-4} $$

$$ \int \frac{1}{y}\,{\rm d}y = \int \frac{1}{x^2-4}\,{\rm d} x $$

$$ \ln y + C = \frac{1}{4} \ln \left( \frac{x-2}{x+2} \right) $$